# android have two buttons and one is always clicked

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, button

How do I make two buttons next to each, the one button defaults to clicked and whenever a button is pressed the other is unpressed?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds like a `RadioButton`

Comment: I looked at radio buttons but I am looking for the look of a normal button

Comment: use 2 drawables and set it to buttons
1st drawable for pressed button
2nd drawable for normal button
and toggle it over each others click

Comment: thanks that makes sense

Comment: to Press button try this maybe it's help You 
       btn.performClick();

Comment: have you [checked below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37184275/2826147) ?@AdamKatz

Comment: Thanks I got it to work a little differently, but i will give you a tick so others can see a working way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/line_bet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/txtWork"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#607d8b"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size" />
    </LinearLayout >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/txtNot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size" />
    </LinearLayout >
</LinearLayout >
```

Now , do something like

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);

        SetButtonChecked(true);
    }

private void SetButtonChecked(boolean isSelected) {
        if (isSelected) {
            txtWork.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActvityName.class, R.color.colorAccent));
            txtWork.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
        } else {
            txtWork.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActvityName.class, R.color.white));
            txtWork.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent));
        }
    }
```